# Putting dynamic data in QT and can selection it

Tags: qt

I want to do the next.

I have a program that must search and show some files. Before, I will do it with a QTextEdit, searching in the system and appending it when I found one.

Now I want to to the next: I want to show the name of the files but I want to select it in the GUI and, in anohter text edit, show the first line in the document.

So, I want to transform any file in something that I can select it (like a Radio Button, a check button or something like this).

I search info in the web but I dont found anything.

Anyone knows what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you use something like a list view (list of selectable items) to do this. Fortunatley Qt has one! called QListView :)

See this link: [QListView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlistview.html)

You add one entry to the listview per file (for exampe). And then when you click/select an entry this triggers an event which you can make display the contents of the file in a nearby text box.

Comment: I finally used a QListWidget agaisnt a QListView but the QListView works too. THanks!

Comment: @Elseine ah, well done, its probably just as good to be honest :) - whatever works in this case.